# Iptables: Matching packets leaving a bridged interface

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables, netfilter

*Apologies if you've already seen this over on serverfault, but it's been on there for several days now, and I've had absolutely no traction...*

---

I'm building a firewall configuration tool based on iptables, and trying to get a "bump in the wire" scenario working.

Given a setup with `eth0` and `eth1` in a bridge `br0` and a third interface `eth2`:

```
    |          |         |
   eth0       eth1      eth2
    | == br0== |         |
          |              |
          |              |
         --- linux node ---
```

In this scenario, lets say I want TCP port 80 traffic to be dropped if it is going to the network attached to `eth0`, but allow it to `eth1`.

I am therefore trying to reliably match packets that go out over the specific interface `eth0`.

If I add the following iptables rule in the `filter` table:

```
-A FORWARD -o br0 --physdev-out eth0 -j LOG
```

Given a packet that originates from `eth1` (the other half of the bridge), then the rule matches just fine, logging:

```
... IN=br0 OUT=br0 PHYSIN=eth2 PHYSOUT=eth1 ...
```

However if the packet origniates from `eth2`, then the rule no longer matches.

I appears that the routing algorithm can't determine which of the bridged interfaces to choose, so the packet is sent out over both interfaces in the bridge.

If I add another more promiscuous log rule, then I get the following log output for that packet:

```
... IN=eth2 OUT=br0 ...
```

My guess is that in the first case, the routing algorithm can just choose the other interface on the bridge since that packet shouldn't go out the way it came.  In the second case, it hasn't chosen a specific interface and you then get no physdev information at all!

However, if the bridge has learned the destination MAC address (as shown by `brctl showmacs br0`) then it can determine the correct interface, and you get physdev informatino again.

(There is also a third case: where the bridge comprises three interfaces that this seems to apply to , then it still can't establish a single interface to send the packet on just be excluding the source interface.)

So, the question is, how can I reliably match packets the go out over `eth0` regardless?

Given the example I gave at the start, it is not enough to just match packets that will be routed out over multiple interfaces, one of which is `eth0` (though that would be useful in other scenarios). I want to be able to treat the traffic for `eth0` and `eth1` differently, allowing the traffic to `eth1`, but not `eth0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reasons for observed behviour**

The reason that iptables doesn't get the physical bridge information when the packet arrives from a non-bridged interface is that the packet has never been near the bridging mechanism, even though at this point we know we are sending it out on the bridge.

In the case where the packet did arrive over a bridge port, but it is an N>2 bridge, the problem is that the iptables PHYSDEV extention only provides for their being one value for "out", so it just doesn't bother telling us if there are two.

**Solution**

Use ebtables instead of iptables.  The ebtables `OUTPUT` chain will know which physical bridged interface it is sending packets out on.

In the scenario above, where you want to filter packets that are leaving via a specific bridged interface (`eth0`), regardless of how it arrived into the system, add an ebtables rule along the following lines:

```
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j <target>
```

In a more complex scenario, where you want to filter packets arriving from a specific interface, and leaving via a bridged interface, it gets harder. Say we want to drop all traffic from `eth2` (non-bridged) going to `eth0` (bridged as part of `br0`) we need to add this rule to **iptables**:

```
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o br0 -j MARK --set-mark 1234
```

This will mark any packet that comes from `eth2` and is bound for the bridge. Then we add this rule to **ebtables**:

```
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 --mark 1234 -j DROP
```

Which will `DROP` any packet marked by iptables  (as being from `eth2`) that is egressing via the specific bridge port `eth0`.

**Acknowledgements**

Thanks goes out to Pascal Hambourg over at the netfilter iptables mailing list for his help in coming up with this solution.